# Load Data while Scrolling Page Down with jQuery and PHP

Tags: jquery, scroll

Using mootools, created an aplication to load data while scrolling page down by handle the scroll event with following Mootools calculation

```
window.getScrollSize().y-window.getScroll().y-window.getSize().y < PRELOAD_DISTANCE;
```

Here

```
PRELOAD_DISTANCE = 150
```

What is the Jquery alternate for  following

```
window.getScrollSize().y-window.getScroll().y-window.getSize().y < PRELOAD_DISTANCE;
```

Any help please

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop() - $(document).height() < PRELOAD_DISTANCE;
```